# Regex + Java - extract from tags not working!

Tags: java, regex

the following takes contents of an HTML file (input)

```
input = input.replaceAll(".*?<span class=\"xgui.*?\">(.*?)</span>.*?", "<cite>$1</cite>");
```

The idea is to remove the span element and leave the contents. Note that the class of the span can be xgui *anything*. However, the code is not working.

It spits out this:

```
 <h4><span class="xguiitem">Primary</span> field </h4>
```

Which is identical to input; ie, it is not doing anything at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Actually it works: see [here](http://ideone.com/KsURz).

Comment: Oh, jeez. I made a dumb mistake about 100 lines before this. Thanks lol

Comment: the mistake is using regular expressions to parse a non-regular language, use XLST or a proper HTML/XHML parser

Comment: but note: it may not be doing what you think. remove the `.*?` at the beginning and the end of your expression to only replace the span without outer text.

Comment: @Jarrod You're right if you talk about parsing of general HTML/XHTML, but for very specific cases (if you know the structure beforehand as in this case) it can work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting note (as also mentioned in the comments): please do not parse arbitrary HTML using regular expressions.

Nevertheless if you know the html structure beforehand and if you have a very specific task you might do it with a regex replacement.

In your case the expression works almost fine. Just a remark about the `.*?` at the beginning and the end of your expression:

- `.*?` at the end will not match anything at any time, because it can not get ungreedier than matching nothing.
- `.*?` at the beginning will match anything from start to the actual `<span...` because a match starting early will always count higher than any non-greediness.

Thus, you can get rid of them and use the following

```
input = input.replaceAll("<span class=\"xgui.*?\">(.*?)</span>", "<cite>$1</cite>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regexp to manipulate HTML. It may work for some cases, but you are trying to parse a context-free grammar with regular expressions. 
XSLT is the way to go here.

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand why you have those "?" all over, can you try:

```
input = input.replaceAll(".*<span class=\"xgui.*\">(.*)</span>.*", "<cite>$1</cite>");
```

Comment: I thought they made they made the .* non-greedy?

Comment: Also, your code did not work.